# How to insert a space between Chinese words and English words in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-text

As I know ，Adding space between Chinese words and English words looks more beautiful.
Like :

```
我是 abc 的朋友
```

looks better then

```
我是abc的朋友
```

And this behavior is automatic support by the iOS since iOS 13.
But flutter use it's own engine to render text. So I want to know any solution to obtain this feature on flutter.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using regEx & replace to add spaces. https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.4/dart-core/String/replaceAllMapped.html

```
 String test = "我是abc的朋友";
  final newString = test.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'(\w+)'), (match) {
  return ' ${match.group(0)} ';
});
  print(newString); //我是 abc 的朋友
```

You might want to try other regex patterns according to your strings.